# Can't inject EPartService

Tags: eclipse, e4

In my bundle activator I try to inject fields 'IEventBroker' and 'EPartService'. But injected only first. Code follows:

```
@Inject
IEventBroker m_broker;
@Inject
EPartService m_part_service;

public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {

    IEclipseContext service_context = EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext(context);
    ContextInjectionFactory.inject(this, service_context);
    boolean contains = service_context.containsKey(EPartService.class);

    // contains is always "true", but m_part_service is always "null"
    // all follows invocations returns "null" too
    //
    // service_context.get(EPartService.class); 
    // service_context.getActiveLeaf().getActive(EPartService.class);   
    // service_context.getActiveLeaf().getLocal(EPartService.class);    
    // context.getServiceReference(EPartService.class); 

    // m_broker always non-null
    m_broker.subscribe(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE, new EventHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event)
            {
                // ... bla bla bla
            }
        });
}
```

In internal lists of IEclipseContext I found EPartService.
Can you help me? What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundle activators are not injected so you can't use `@Inject`.

The context returned by `EclipseContextFactory.getServiceContext` has very limited contents and can't be used to access things like `EPartService`.

In any case the bundle activator generally isn't even run until something else in your plugin is used, so it would be too late the see the startup complete message anyway.

So all this means you can't do what you want in the bundle activator `start` method.

To get notified about the app startup complete event you can use the application LifeCycle class or define an AddOn - both these classes are injected.

In those classes use a method like:

```
@Optional
@Inject
public void appStartupComplete(@UIEventTopic(UIEvents.UILifeCycle.APP_STARTUP_COMPLETE)
                               org.osgi.service.event.Event event)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My application started with own config.ini. In this config I start my plugins in needed order. Bundle with code above is not application plugin. And I need to open part when get message from TCP socket. So I need inject EPartService to open part in classes not related to UI. Code with 'm_broker' I added to show that 'IEventBroker' service was injected and it is not related to my question. I need EPartService....

Comment: The bundle activator is still the wrong place. Use an AddOn where injection will work properly.

Comment: If the plugin is not the main application plugin use a fragment.e4xmi for the AddOn

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I did AddOn. It works. But I need to know when Window opened, not app started. Because I have specific configuration of my application which works only in tray, and window can be opened by menu from tray. I try to listen UIEvents.TrimmedWindow.TOPIC_ALL and UIEvents.Window.TOPIC_ALL but nothing happens...

Comment: Please don't ask follow up questions in comments - ask a new question.